# Specify ReturnUri in ValidatePrincipal CookieAuthenticationEvents

Tags: authentication, .net-core

I've followed the instructions on this [Microsoft Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1#react-to-back-end-changes) to invalidate the cookie.
In ValidatePrincipal() I call a custom method, which returns an url where the user should be redirected because the user was disabled.

How can I control from ValidatePrincipal to which page the user will be redirected?

I tried to call this inside ValidatePrincipal:

```
            await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CustomCookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = MyRedirectPage
            });
```

But this does nothing. I tried to access the RedirectUri in an override method for RedirectToLogin, but the value is not there.
What else can I try to redirect to a specific page, when ValidatePrincip() invalidates the cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. 
In my override of ValidatePrincipal I set a custom Item in the HTTPContext.

In my override of RedirectToLogin I read the value of the HttpContext and set the context.response.RedirectUri manually